# Is there an inverse of 'pathname-directory'?

Tags: common-lisp

I wonder if there's a function such that:

```
(equal path (some-function (pathname-directory path)))
```

Comment: How could that be possible? `pathname-directory` discards information about the original path, how could `some-function` recover it?

Comment: Thinking about it. If you have two paths in the same directory, `pathname-directory` will return the same result for both of them. How could a function possibly know which of the two original paths to return for it?

Comment: @Barmar Good point. I was just thinking of a pathname with a nil for name. But in general its not possible, like you say.

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you only care about directory components, its:

```
(defun some-function (list)
  (make-pathname :directory list))
```